# Consolidating RSS feed in a reader

Tags: rss, rss-reader, rss2

By `RSS 2.0` specification,  `link`, `title` and `description` are required elements. In reality though, any of those three can be missing. I read data from multiple feeds and I want to display them in a similar manner, how can I consolidate the data?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the Really simple syndication, you can make those elements in the resulting object/table:

**link** - There are several elements that can contain a link. Other than `<link>` itself, there is`<guid>`. If `permalink="true"`, it is a good link. If not permalink, it can be a link as well, but it may lead nowhere. There can also be `<enclosure>` (one or more), however, they link to files or streams, not webpages.

**title** - If there is no `<title>`, you can take a piece of `<description>`, remove any HTML from it though.

**description** - If `<description>` isn't present, leave it empty.

**guid** - If it's not present, select first available combination from those:

`link-<pubDate>`, `link-title`, `link`, `title-<pubDate>`, `title`, `<pubDate>`

The generated guid doesn't have to be really unique, be aware of that.

**pubDate** - if you must show some date and it's not present, generate one upon saving.

Comment: Be careful with <guid> has links. Sometimes they look like links but do not actually point to anything... they're really guids and their content should not be interpreted as having any meaningful sense.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, but I forgot to mention it. Also, I found no `<uri>` or `<url>` in any specification, so now I wonder why is it present in Java's com.sun.syndication.feed.rss.Item.